# NT OS Kernel using port 8888

Tags: networking, windows-10, java

I am trying to setup an application on `Windows 10 Pro` that uses port `8888`; I am not able to successfully set this application up as `ntoskrnl` is actively using port `8888`. I am not sure why the system is doing this and I am searching for a solution as the application cannot be reconfigured to use a different port. The application is a simple `JSTL` interface to a `card reader` attached to the computer; because `8888` is in use the application cannot connect to the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Is the card reader restricted to using port 8888?

If so, it might be possible that Windows has already assigned some service to look after the card reader and your application is clashing with it. I recall installing software for a device (mobile phone as I recall) and it very clearly stated "do not plug the phone in before installing", which implies that if I did then the OS may take over the device and mess up the software access.

(should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation points yet)

Comment: Thanks Nick! This is good feedback.I'm looking into it now.